# How to reset counter when objective is reached

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this snippet of code:

```
var cat = solutions
                .Descendants("Solution")
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    ID = (string)x.Element("ID"),
                    Properties = x.Elements("Property").Select(p => new
                    {
                        Name = (string) p.Element("Name"),
                        Value = (string) p.Element("Value"),

                        idx = i++
                    })
                    .Where(y => indexesToChoose.Contains(y.idx))
                    .OrderBy(z => indexesToChoose.FindIndex(p => p == z.idx))
                    .ToList()
                });
```

I only want it to count till 11, then reset to 0 to start over, so example it would read 8,9,10,11,0,1 etc.

Comment: What kind of object or collection is x?

Comment: @Pow-Ian updated its filtering results from an xml doc each count is the next property name/value pair in the xmldoc.

Comment: How about `idx` and `i` where are they declared? It looks like `idx` is a property of `x` because of `y.idx` but I can't be sure because you did not de-reference it as `x.idx`

Comment: @Pow-Ian idx is not declared prior to its usage as  `idx = i++`   `i` is declared as `int i = 0;`  simply when i++ hits 11, i want it to reset i's value to 0 instead of continuing to 12.

Comment: Why not `idx = (i < 12 ? i++ : i  = 0);`? Are you worried about stopping it or letting it reset? if you need to stop the loop it is a lot harder than resetting.

Comment: @Pow-Ian i actually think thats exactly what im looking for, been a long day /sigh lol.

Comment: it's cool; I would have to lie to tell you I have never had this happen to me ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use modulus:

```
idx = i++ % 12
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only want the value of `idx` to go to 11 and then roll over you can try this instead of just i++:

`idx = (i < 12 ? i++ : i = 0);`